# jQuery event for HTML file input "ok button" click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, file-upload

I'm having a problem with a script that generates a live preview of the image file that I select. The problem is that there is a spike in memory when I select a file using the file input, so my on('change') method fires much too late for a useful user response. Now if I hit Ctrl+F5, sometimes the browser becomes much more responsive and generates the preview very quickly. The lag isn't in the inlining of image data, but the time between when the user selects "open" on the file dialog box and when the onChange event fires. I don't know how to track what's going on in between those two events.

I have hidden the HTML file input tag via CSS positioning and triggered the click event when I click on a separate span element. The input tag has the on('change') function registered. On change, I notify the user that the image preview is being generated. When the generation is complete, I notify "Preview complete". As I stated before, due to the fact that the onchange event is lagged due to memory spikes, I never end up seeing the intermediary "please wait..." text. This happens both in Firefox and Chrome.

**javascript**

```
var imageSelectClass = '';
var imageSelectDefaultBGSize = 'auto';
var imageSelectWorkingBGSize = '100%';
var imageSelectDefaultUrl = '';
var imageSelectNoPreviewUrl = '';

function resetImageSelection(resetImage, toOriginalImage) {
    $('.image-select-text').text("");
    $('.image-select-text').css("opacity", 1);
    $('.' + imageSelectClass).css('backgroundSize', imageSelectDefaultBGSize);
    if (resetImage) {
        if (toOriginalImage) $('.' + imageSelectClass).css('backgroundSize', imageSelectWorkingBGSize);
        if (imageSelectDefaultUrl != imageSelectNoPreviewUrl) {
            $('.' + imageSelectClass).css('backgroundImage', "url('" + (toOriginalImage ? imageSelectDefaultUrl : imageSelectNoPreviewUrl) + "')");
        }
    }
}

function handleImageSelection(evt) {

    // Clear the photo box
    resetImageSelection(true, true);

    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            resetImageSelection(true, true);
            $('#' + imageSelectClass).replaceWith($('#' + imageSelectClass).clone());
            makeIntoImageSelection(imageSelectClass, imageSelectDefaultUrl, imageSelectNoPreviewUrl, imageSelectDefaultBGSize, imageSelectWorkingBGSize);
            newTextMessage("Not an image file!", 2000, 400);
            continue;
        }

        var isValidPreview = f.type.match('image\/(jp(e?)g|png|gif|bmp)');
        //var reader = new FileReader();
        var theType = /\/(.*)/.exec(f.type)[1].toUpperCase();

        // Limit preview to 20MB file sizes
        var limit = 20971520;
        if (f.size < limit) {
            if (isValidPreview) {
                resetImageSelection(false, false);
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                if (URL.createObjectURL) {
                    newTextMessage("Preview generated.", 3000, 400);
                    $('.' + imageSelectClass).css('backgroundSize', imageSelectWorkingBGSize);
                    $('.' + imageSelectClass).css('backgroundImage', "url('" + URL.createObjectURL(f) + "')");
                } else {
                    resetImageSelection(true, false);
                    newTextMessage("Sorry, but your browser doesn't support image previews.", 0, 0);
                }
            } else {
                resetImageSelection(true, false);
                newTextMessage(theType + " images can't be previewed 'on-the-fly'. However it will be converted when you save.", 0, 0);
            }
        } else {
            resetImageSelection(true, false);
            newTextMessage("On-the-fly previews only available for files <= " + (limit/1024/1024) + "MB", 0, 0);
        }

    }
}

function makeIntoImageSelection(id, defaultUrl, noPreviewUrl, defaultBGSize, workingBGSize) {
    imageSelectClass = id;
    originalCanvasWidth = $('.' + id).width();
    originalCanvasHeight = $('.' + id).height();
    imageSelectDefaultBGSize = defaultBGSize;
    imageSelectWorkingBGSize = workingBGSize;
    imageSelectDefaultUrl = defaultUrl;
    imageSelectNoPreviewUrl = noPreviewUrl;

    // When span is clicked, trigger the file input
    $('span.' + id).on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#' + id).click();
        newTextMessage("Select an image.", 3000, 400);
    });
    $('#' + id).on('change', function (evt) {
        newTextMessage("Generating preview...", 2000, 400);
        handleImageSelection(evt);
    });
    $('.image-select-text').css('maxWidth', $('.image-select.' + id + ' span').css('width'));
}

function newTextMessage(msg, display_time, fadeDelay) {
    $('.image-select-text').text(msg);
    $('.image-select-text').css("opacity", 1);
    if (display_time > 0) {
        $('.image-select-text').delay(display_time).fadeTo(fadeDelay, 0, function() {
            $('.image-select-text').text("");
            $('.image-select-text').css("opacity", 1);
        });
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/albums/4/photographs" class="new_photograph" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_photograph" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>
    <input class="image-select" id="photograph_photo" name="photograph[photo]" type="file">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="image-select photograph_photo" style="background-size: 100%;"></span><br>
                    <span class="image-select-text" style="opacity: 1;"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="photograph_title">Title</label><br><input id="photograph_title" name="photograph[title]" size="50" type="text" data-cip-id="photograph_title"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="photograph_description">Description</label><br><textarea id="photograph_description" name="photograph[description]"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="actions">
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Photograph">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Inline Javascript at end of document**

```
makeIntoImageSelection('photograph_photo', '[url of original image file if any]', '[url of global default image file]', '100%', '100%');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really can't say what was causing such lag, but I'm going to chalk it up to "weird circumstances. A computer restart had essentially 'fixed' the problem.